# Unity TCG Game NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I know this is a popular Question, but unfortunately no of the solutions work for me.
So basically what I try to do is creating an Trading Card Game in Unity.
I have a Script called "Card" that is basically "what is a card".
The script does NOT derive from MonoBehaviour, what means I can use constructors right ?

```
// Construktor 
public Card (string name, string info, string rar, string edi, int id){
    cardName = name;
    switch (rar) {
    case "Common":
        rarity = Rarity.Common;
        break;
    case "Rar":
        rarity = Rarity.Rar;
        break;
    case "Epic":
        rarity = Rarity.Epic;
        break;
    case "Legendary":
        rarity = Rarity.Legendary;
        break;



    }

    cardInfo = info;


    switch (edi) {
    case "Normal":
        edition = Edition.Normal;
        break;

    case "Special":
        edition = Edition.Special;
        break;

    }

    cardId = id;
    picture = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Cards/" + name );



}
```

Okay so the Player should have a script called "CardCollection" with is his Collection of Cards. 
In this Script I want a List of Cards. 
But when I do something like

```
    public List<Card> cardCollection;
....
    cardCollection.Add (new Card ("Alex","whatever", "Rar", "Normal", 0001));
```

I do get: 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CardCollection.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/SideScroll/CardCollection.cs:24)

And I don't know why, where is my mistake ?

Comment: `public List<Card> cardCollection;` should be `public List<Card> cardCollection = new List<Card>()` before you can do `cardCollection.Add...`.

Comment: Oh god im so stupid. Thank you very much